# PayPal integration 400 Bad Request / Order could not be captured

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to integrate PayPal and I get the error below

You can test the code here with any PayPal sandbox buyer account:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/khaledabdelzaher/pen/YzWKVaQ)

Here is the code I'm using

```
    paypal.Buttons({
  createOrder: function (data, actions) {
    // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
    return actions.order.create({
      purchase_units: [{
        amount: {
          value: '5.00'
        }
      }]
    });
  },
  onApprove: function (data, actions) {
    // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
    return actions.order.capture().then(details => {
      // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
      alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
    });
  }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

more about the error

[image: more about the error]

[image: more about the error]

Comment: You should probably focus on the bad request 400 error that happens right before...

Comment: Yes it's related I think

Comment: Yeah, the URL ends in `capture` so it's pretty safe to say it's related :)

Comment: As Chris mentioned you should expand the POST 400 Bad Request, and post those full details.

Comment: @PrestonPHX done, updated my question

Comment: Huh, well that's not the actual response body or headers. I guess you'll have to have the Network tab open with Preserve/Persist Log checked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testing your Codepen from the Network tab, you are getting a COMPLIANCE_VIOLATION -- probably due to the country of the account you are testing with not being properly set up in sandbox.

Try simply using a different country for your testing within sandbox. Create a new business account at https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts%2F , and then create a new REST app with a new ClientID/Secret for it.